# JVMTI Tags in HeapDump or separate mapping file

Tags: java, java-native-interface, heap-dump, jvmti

In addition to the information in a heap dump I need to also get the information about potential tags set to an object via JVMTI. Ideally, these values should be stored directly in the heap dump together with the rest of the instance information, but this does not seem to be supported. Or anyone knows a way?

Alternatively I was thinking of a mapping file that holds tags mapped to the corresponding object ids from the heap dump (which, if I'm not mistaken, are the memory addresses of the objects at the time the dump was created). If the VM would be paused I could maybe take the dump creation, tagging the objects and writing that mapping before letting the VM continue. Doesn't seem like the best approach ever though. Any other ideas?

Any idea of how / where I could get access to the tag information other than jvmtis getTag(object) method?

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the docs:

> Tags are local to the (JVMTI) environment; that is, the tags of one environment are not visible in another.

A mapping table would be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Absolutely right. Was hoping for something I have overseen though. The idea with the mapping table might have a problem as well. The whole operation, (1. tag the objects, 2. create the heap dump, and then 3. create the mapping file) won't be atomic. Theoretically the objects might be moved around in memory between 2 and 3 I fear. Do you know of a way how to prevent that from happening? I definitely can suspend all the threads but this would not prevent the GC from moving things around (although no new garbage would be created).

Comment: Since I cannot do all this in one of the callbacks while iterating through the heap (which ensure that during the execution of these functions the state of the heap does not change) I'm not sure how reliable the mapping file would be.

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve? I guess it's a question of whether you're going down the right path. If so, follow it to it's conclusion irregardless of the "hacks" necessary. Otherwise there may be another choice.

Comment: I'm need to be able to compare two heap dumps and know exactly which objects from the second dump are which objects from the first. Since the ids in the dumps are memory addresses though this simply doesn't work (as object can change their position in memory). So I have no why have really comparing the objects and see what changed on which object.